# How to get access to external storage since environment.getexternalstoragedirectory() is deprecated

Tags: java, android

I am new in android and I want to read all the files from external storage in order to make a file explorer app but I can't find a way to access those files. What should I use instead of environment.getexternalstoragedirectory()?

Comment: The API should give you an adequate substitute, no? What have you found when you inspected the Environment API?

Comment: Here is a [link to the API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) which seems to suggest several options as well as tell why this method has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, `getExternalMediaDir`() ... [Read more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

For example (`getExternalFilesDir`) :

```
public static File getAppFileDir(Context context) {
    File file;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        file = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    } else {
        file = context.getFilesDir();
    }
    return file;
}
```

will give you:

> android/data/data/your_package_name/files

---

If you still want to use `getExternalStorageDirectory`:

```
public static File getExternalStorageDirectory(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    } else {
        try {
            File file = getAppFileDir(context);
            if (null != file) {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                return file.getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile();
            } else {
                return new File("");
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new File("");
        }
    }
}
```

But don't use it in a release app, cause I'm not sure if it will work on all devices.